# Тип данных в JS

Tags: javascript, html

Есть часть сайта для регистрации (человек в форме заполняет данные о количестве людей и часов):

```
<form action="" class="form">
                    <section class="selectPeople">
                        <input type="range" min="2" max="20" step="1"  name="people" id="peopleRange">
                        <p >Количество человек</p> <span id="peopleCol"></span>
                    </section>
                    <section class="selectTime">
                        <input type="range" min="15" max="60" step="15"  name="time" id="timeRange">
                        <p >Время игры</p> <span id="timeCol"></span>
                    </section>
                    <section class="price">
                        <p>Стоимость игры</p>
                        <span id="price"></span>
                    </section>
                </form>


var peopleCol = document.querySelector('#peopleCol');
    var peopleRange = document.querySelector('#peopleRange');
    peopleCol.innerHTML = peopleRange.value;
    peopleRange.oninput = function(){
        peopleCol.innerHTML = peopleRange.value;
    }
    var timeRange = document.querySelector('#timeRange');
    var timeCol = document.querySelector('#timeCol');
    timeCol.innerHTML = timeRange.value;
    timeRange.oninput = function(){
        timeCol.innerHTML = timeRange.value;
    }
```

Далее необходимо посчитать цену заказа. Решил это реализовать следующим кодом:

```
var price = document.querySelector('#price');
    price.innerHTML = 60 * Number(peopleCol.value) * (Number(timeCol.value)/15);
```

Но в резудьтате выдает NAN. Я так понимаю что я где то напутал с типом данных в нужной мне формуле. Подскажите, где б надо поправить

Comment: ну вы оперируете изначально `innerHTML`, а потом пытаетесь `value` взять у элемента, у которого такого атрибута нет. Т.е. надо либо уж до конца использовать `innerHTML`, либо использовать поле, где есть `value`

Comment: @Vlad Madara Сергей прав, используйте `price.innerHTML = 60 * Number(peopleCol.innerHTML) * (Number(timeCol.innerHTML)/15);` и всё заработает.

Comment: innerHTML помог! спасибо, вот только возникла другая проблема, надо чтоб этот ползунок динамически меня эту саму цену, без перезагрузки сайта

Comment: @Vlad Madara Так он и меняет динамически )

Answer (score 1):

Для наглядности пример:

```js
var peopleCol = document.querySelector('#peopleCol');
var peopleRange = document.querySelector('#peopleRange');
peopleCol.innerHTML = peopleRange.value;
peopleRange.oninput = function() {
  peopleCol.innerHTML = peopleRange.value;
};
var timeRange = document.querySelector('#timeRange');
var timeCol = document.querySelector('#timeCol');
timeCol.innerHTML = timeRange.value;
timeRange.oninput = function() {
  timeCol.innerHTML = timeRange.value;
};

peopleRange.onchange = function() {
  var price = document.querySelector('#price');
  price.innerHTML = 60 * Number(peopleCol.innerHTML) * (Number(timeCol.innerHTML) / 15);
};
timeRange.onchange = function() {
  var price = document.querySelector('#price');
  price.innerHTML = 60 * Number(peopleCol.innerHTML) * (Number(timeCol.innerHTML) / 15);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" class="form">
  <section class="selectPeople">
    <input type="range" min="2" max="20" step="1" name="people" id="peopleRange">
    <p>Количество человек</p> <span id="peopleCol"></span>
  </section>
  <section class="selectTime">
    <input type="range" min="15" max="60" step="15" name="time" id="timeRange">
    <p>Время игры</p> <span id="timeCol"></span>
  </section>
  <section class="price">
    <p>Стоимость игры</p>
    <span id="price"></span>
  </section>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let peopleCol = document.querySelector('#peopleCol');
let peopleRange = document.querySelector('#peopleRange');
let timeRange = document.querySelector('#timeRange');
let timeCol = document.querySelector('#timeCol');
let price = document.querySelector('#price');

//выставляем значения при инициалиации
peopleCol.textContent = peopleRange.value;
timeCol.textContent = timeRange.value;
price.textContent = 60 * peopleRange.value * (timeRange.value / 15)

//Событие при изменении кол-ва людей
peopleRange.addEventListener("change", function() {
  peopleCol.textContent = this.value;
  price.textContent = 60 * this.value * (timeRange.value / 15)
})

//Событие изменении значений времени
timeRange.addEventListener("change", function() {
  timeCol.textContent = this.value;
  price.textContent = 60 * peopleRange.value * (this.value / 15)
})
```

```html
<form action="" class="form">
  <section class="selectPeople">
    <input type="range" min="2" max="20" step="1" name="people" id="peopleRange">
    <p>Количество человек</p> <span id="peopleCol"></span>
  </section>
  <section class="selectTime">
    <input type="range" min="15" max="60" step="15" name="time" id="timeRange">
    <p>Время игры</p> <span id="timeCol"></span>
  </section>
  <section class="price">
    <p>Стоимость игры</p>
    <span id="price"></span>
  </section>
</form>
```